# Javascript dynamic answer text box

Tags: javascript, jsp, scriptlet

Hello Good Morning guys,
I am creating one polling like page using jsp and scriplet, first thing i created is jsp page having question and answer. but problem is that I need n number of answer so i created like if loop in jsp having a button add, if user click add button means new text box have to open. but it not working, Please tell me some solution

```html
<%@page import="com.sun.xml.internal.txw2.Document"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Main</title>
</head>
<body>
     <form action="survey1.jsp" method="post">
  <div>
   <label>Question &nbsp<input type="text" name="ques"></label><br>
   <label><input type="button" value="AddQues" name="add"></label>
   <%
    if (request.getParameter("add") == "add") {
   %>
   <label>Answer1 &nbsp<input type="text" name="ans1"></label><br>
   <%
    } else {
   %>
   <label><input type="submit" value="Submit"></label>
   <%
    }
   %>
  </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add the complete code..specially where you are looping

Answer (score 2):

**I would advice you following practices**

1. To add new answer give a button say "add answer" and  use Jquery and its [show hide](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show) method

   It would give a better view and easy interface to the user .
2. Better use **text area** instead of **text** as **input type** as you can set the size of the text area accordingly.
3. Wherever you are looping , make sure within the loop along with the div and other elements your `<form>` should also be dynamically created ,i.e there would be a new `<form>`for each question so that every question can be answered.
4. Manage your database carefully , i.e for each question there would be multiple answers , so link the question and answer with a **unique id** for eg if the question has an id 7 , then every answer to this question must have id as 7 (you can use auto increment to this column if you are using mysql), so that whenever you apply join to the database query you can fetch question with id 7 and all the answer corresponding this id .

Hope you got the concept , similarly **like** and **dislike** button can also be implemented